# Understanding textInput and navigating the documentation

Tags: react-native, textinput

three questions:

1) if you have multiple textInput fields how do you determine which one is being used?

2) with both onchangeText and onsubmitEditing what is being returned to the function

```
onSubmitEditing={()=>{this.clearText()}}
onChangeText={(text) => {this.captureInput(text)}}
```

I get that in onChangeText() text gives me the value in the input field. Are there any other parameters being passed back to that function?

Also, in onsubmitEditing() how do I access the event parameters being passed to clearText()?

I've read the documentation found here [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting) but it doesn't answer my question

3) Where in the documentation do you find these answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You just call different handlers to handle them separately:

```
<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.handleFirstInput(text)} />
<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.handleSecondInput(text)} />
```

2) There's no other parameters passed to them. What else do you need? You can set a `ref` on them but avoid that if possible.

Comment: thanks, I've tried to follow the docs on ref's but am confused by them could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090496/why-is-this-refs-workmin-value-undefined