# unable to access component with ref

Tags: react-native, ref

Why is this.workmin.value undefined?

```js
captureInput=(text)=>{
    console.log('captureinput',this.refs.workmin.value)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('RENDER',this.state)


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.bigFont}>{`${this.state.timer + 'TIMER'}`}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.bigFont}>{`${this.state.min + ':' + this.state.sec}`}</Text>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button title='START' onPress={()=>this.startToggle()} />
          <Button title='RESET' onPress={()=>this.resetToggle()} />
        </View>
             <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={[styles.bold,{marginRight:10},{width:112},
                            {textAlign:'right'}]}>
                            Work Timer:</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bold}> min:</Text>
                <TextInput
                   
                   value={Math.floor(this.state.workTime / 60).toString()}
                   ref= {(ref)=>{this.workmin=ref}}
                   style={styles.input}
                   onChangeText={(text) => {this.captureInput(text)}}

                />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`refs` is deprecated, do this instead:

```
<TextInput
  ref={(ref) => {
    this.workmin = ref;
  }}
/>
```

Then you can use it like `this.workmin.focus()`.

Comment: how would I get the value of the input field ?

Comment: You want to get the value in `onSubmitEditing`? Store the updated text from `onChangeText` in a state: `onChangeText={text => setState({ text })}` , then read from `this.state.text`.

Comment: I'm trying to determine which input field is being used.  I thought I could identify which field through a ref

Comment: Don't use ref for that, just call different handlers? See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090054/understanding-textinput-and-navigating-the-documentation/50090490

Comment: that doesn't seem like the best answer. If you have 10 input fields do you really want to duplicate 10 handlers?

Comment: You can use anonymous arrow function instead of explicitly declaring a handler. They should generally be 1-liner difference anyway (different key in `setState`?). If the inputs are together maybe you want a `map`. Maybe you can illustrate with an example to show why this is problematic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170039/discussion-between-dcr-and-riwu).